# pipe-function in loop does not find input

Tags: r, for-loop

I am doing a for loop on a list of files and combining this with the pipe-function. Any idea why my input is not found?

```
for (f in 1:length(list.vaf)) {
my_vcf=read.table(pipe("grep -v '^##' list.vaf[f] | sed s/^#//"),stringsAsFactors=F,header=T,sep="\t")
...
...}
```

Error:

```
grep: list.vaf[f]: No such file or directory
Error in read.table(pipe("grep -v '^##' list.vaf[f] | sed s/^#//"), stringsAsFactors = F,  : 
  no lines available in input

> list.vaf[1]
[1] "~/Downloads/Sample1_pcgr_acmg.grch37.vcf"
```

This works:

```
for (f in 1:length(list.vaf)) {
my_vcf=read.table(pipe("grep -v '^##' ~/Downloads/Sample1_pcgr_acmg.grch37.vcf | sed s/^#//"),stringsAsFactors=F,header=T,sep="\t")
...
...}
```

Comment: Try `pipe_string<-paste("grep -v '^##'", list.vaf[f], " | sed s/^#//")`, then `read.table(pipe(pipe_string))`.

Comment: Or `p <- pipe(paste("grep -v '^##'", list.vaf[f], " | sed s/^#//"))`, then `read.table(p, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, etc)`.